# How do I write the data from Scapy into a CSV file

Tags: python, scapy

Using Scapy I have extracted the ethernet frame length, IP payload size, and the header length I would like to write this information to a csv file for further examination

```
from scapy.all import *

pcap = rdpcap('example.pcap')
out = open("out.csv", "wb")

for pkts in pcap:
    ethernet_header = (len(pkts)) # IP payload size
    ip_pload = (len(pkts.payload) - 20) # Ethernet frame length
    ip_header = (len(pkts.payload)) # Total length IP header
    print(ip_pload, len(pkts), ip_header)

    out.write(ethernet_header, ip_pload, ip_header)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [builtin `csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer), it's quite easy to use:

```py
import csv
with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for pkts in pcap:
        ethernet_header = (len(pkts)) # IP payload size
        ip_pload = (len(pkts.payload) - 20) # Ethernet frame length
        ip_header = (len(pkts.payload)) # Total length IP header
        writer.writerow([ethernet_header, ip_pload, ip_header])
```